# How to get full HTML page source from closed shadow DOM

Tags: html, web-scraping, shadow-dom, headless-browser

I implemented a web scraper for certain tasks.
But I can't find a way to get the full HTML page source after executing JavaScript, and what's important - including with closed shadow DOM. I tried Selenium, Pypiter, CEF, Selenoid and other.

Max achievement: code after JavaScript executes but without closed shadow DOM elements.

Is there a solution for mу task?

Comment: The whole/sole purpose of ``closed`` shadowDOM is to **not** be accessible. If *you* close your front-door, you don't want anyone else to be able to open it...

Comment: Greatest saying, but helpless )))

Comment: Can you confirm the url?

Comment: what url did you mean ?

Comment: As @Danny'365CSI'Engelman says, there's no way of doing this without access to the underlying browser internals. At that point, you might as well write your own browser for the sole purpose of breaking the standards the web is built upon. If it's that important, ask the people who created the closed shadowDOM for access.

Comment: tnx 4 u comment. i think abount create fork from chomiun... perhaps there is another way to get the page's source code? I don't need direct access to the closed shadow-root elements from my code, I just need the source page code that describes them - properties, links etc.

Comment: One way to open closed shadow DOM is to load a script before everything else that replaces attachShadow or whatever it is called and it will call the original with the open mode instead